# How do I pass parameters to react?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to pass a parameter to my react project. I set it up with create-react-app.

I set up package.json like so:

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

index.js:

```
console.log(process.argv)
```

I start it up and pass in my parameter:

```
yarn start --serverPort=3531
```

But then process.argv is just an empty array. How can I pass parameters to the react app?

Comment: @RobC That gives me the same result, and a warning in the console:


```warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.```

Comment: Using ```yarn start -- --serverPort=3531``` is what I'm referring to above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we actually want is to define an [Environment Variable](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/) that our React instance can reach from within that environment, and here ours is `NodeJS`

What we are doing here: `yarn start --serverPort=3531`, is that we are passing the `yarn` command a parameter `serverPort` with the value of `3531`.

While what we should do is to declare an Environment Variable such as `PORT`, then reach it with the help of `process.env` which will allow us access the current used environment.

Note that: "By convention, environment variables should have UPPER CASE names."

We change our start script in `package.json` to fit with the above:

`PORT=3000 && webpack-dev-server --open --mode development`

You can then access its value via: `process.env.PORT // output --> 3000`.

This is a quick workaround, but, I suggest you [read more about setting up environment variables.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) as in CRA docs.